# Is it possible to create a floating window using codeigniter? How would I do it?

Tags: css, codeigniter

I would like to ask you guys if how can I create a floating window in code igniter. The scenario is when I clicked a textbox it would show a floating window with a close button on the upper right corner. I'm new in using code igniter. Thank you for the ones that would give me solution.

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct, Code igniter is a PHP framework. What you usually build a modal pop up window with is javascript and CSS. The following code should be pretty readable. the `fadeIn();` methods come with jQuery out of the box - and a tricky way of absolutely positioning the box requires a width and height. Here is [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/hc67p/)

### HTML

```
<div class="box">
  This is your box
  <button id="close">close</button>
</div>

<button id="open">open</button>
```

### CSS

```
.box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  
  border: 1px solid red;
  
  display: none;
}
```

### jQuery

```
$('#open').on('click', function() {
  $('.box').fadeIn();
  $(this).hide();
  
});

$('#close').on('click', function() {
  $('.box').fadeOut();
  $('#open').show();
});
```